# Python uses which algorithm for index method?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find out more about python built in methods

I know that python uses Tim Sort as base function in sort()
I want to know what algorithm python use for searching?
for list.index(valve) method and for x in list.

Comment: Iteration. Simple iteration.

Comment: The Python language does not not define this. It is a matter of the implementation like CPython.

Answer (score 1):

Both comments are correct: the Python standard doesn't mandate anything regarding the implementation of `list.index()`. We can somewhat bound our expectations with the fact that realistically, implementations of `index` are (probably) not evil, so even though it is possible to create an `O(n!)` variant, we can probably make the following observations:

- Pre-sorting a `list` and then performing a binary search, despite the tail-end of the algorithm being `O(log n)`, would still be bounded by the sorting, which would be `O(n log n)` if comparison, or `O(n)` if we go beyond comparison. This adds quite a bit of overhead for an algorithm that would still be order `O(n)` on average (and `list` is not a sorted container, so we can't assume it's sorted anyway)
- It's not a requirement for objects to implement total ordering, and it's more than legal to create a barebones `class` that doesn't override `__eq__` or any other relational dunder (e.g., `__le__`, `__gt__`) so implementations would likely err on the side of caution, as the default implementation of `__eq__` is `is`

On the more pragmatic side of things, we can look at the CPython, the reference implementation of Python. The `index` method defined for `list` exists at [listobject.c#L2601](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6373c0d8b59512aa7f0dea7f3fb162b6ed10fa4/Objects/listobject.c#L2601):

- This method takes in the object we are iterating over, `self`; the `value` we are looking for, as well as the `start` and `stop` indices (keeping in mind that the `index` method can be something like `my_list.index(my_val, 10, 20)` if we want to restrict the search to a certain slice).
- The two `if` statements at the beginning recover valid indices in the case where the caller supplies negative values (as Python allows you to specify `-1` in case you want to refer to the last element, or `-2` for the second last element). If a `list` has `10` elements and you want the `-1`'th element, then you want the `9`th element, or `-1 + 10 = 9`. So, if an index is negative, we recover a valid index by adding `len`.

  - In this case, the `len` of the object is stored in the `struct` as `ob_size`, which to my knowledge, is a flexible array object accessible from the macro `Py_SIZE` (as you can see in the code)
- The `for` loop that follows is your run-of-the-mill iteration algorithm. There are some implementation details here that, again, aren't necessarily important:

  - Each iteration grabs the next `PyObject` by dereferencing the flexible array member `ob_item`
  - `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF` are tallying functions used to increment and decrement the reference counter for the current object being examined within the `list`
  - Comparing equality is done using a three-way function `PyObject_RichCompareBool` which returns:

    - `-1` on error
    - `0` if not equal (`false`)
    - `1` if equal (`true`)
  - In case that the value is found, then as one would expect, the index is returned. Otherwise a `ValueError` is raised

Similar things happen in PyPy, where we look instead at [listobject.py#L874](https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy/blob/c3c70d15184ed141b190f44ec1474ec0ef40a179/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py#L874):

- We see PyPy JIT interpreter code here, with `jit_merge_point` [signalling the start of a potential loop](https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy/blob/c3c70d15184ed141b190f44ec1474ec0ef40a179/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py#L881)
- Every time objects are checked, they're first [checked for identity, then equality](https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy/blob/c3c70d15184ed141b190f44ec1474ec0ef40a179/pypy/interpreter/baseobjspace.py#L793)